# Which member of array does the string contain in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string, contains

How can I check if a string contains a member of an array, and return the index (integer) of the relevant member?

Let's say my string is this :

```
$string1 = "stackoverflow.com";
$string2 = "superuser.com";
$r = array("queue" , "stack" , "heap");

get_index($string1 , $r); // returns 1
get_index($string2 , $r); // returns -1 since string2 does not contain any element of array
```

How can I write this function in an elegant (short) and efficient way ?

I found a function (expression ? ) that checks if the string contains a member of an array :

```
(0 < count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', explode(' ', $string)), $array)))
```

but this is a boolean. does the `count()` function return what I want in this statement ?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Just FYI, your one-line is not the best code. An explode, convert and intersect are 'heavy' actions on a big string/array which can be done easier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_index($str, $arr){
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    if(strpos($str, $val) !== false)
    return $key;
    }
return -1;
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/95398

Comment: This only return the first key of the array. The TS wants (if I understand correctly) the amount of matching elements, not just the first key. Apart from that, please see the `break;` in my code.

Comment: I do want the index. Sorry if I worded the problem badly. This answer is exactly what I'm looking for. Though I did not test the others, thanks for all the answers !

Comment: This will only return the FIRST key. If you want all keys, you can use my function with a small change

Answer (score 0):

This will find the number of matching elements in your array, if you want all matching keys, use the commented lines instead:

```
function findMatchingItems($needle, $haystack){
    $foundItems = 0; // start counter
    // $foundItems = array(); // start array to save ALL keys
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value){ // start to loop through all items
        if( strpos($value, $needle)!==false){ 
            ++$foundItems; // if found, increase counter
            // $foundItems[] = $key; // Add the key to the array
        }
    }
    return $foundItems; // return found items
}

findMatchingItems($string1 , $r);
findMatchingItems($string2 , $r);
```

If you want to return all matching keys, just change `$foundItems` to an array and add the keys in the if-statement (switch to the commented lines).

If you only want to know if something matches or not

```
function findMatchingItems($needle, $haystack){
    if( strpos($value, $needle)!==false){ 
        return true;
        break; // <- This is important. This stops the loop, saving time ;)
    }
    return false;// failsave, if no true is returned, this will return
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do a function like this:

```
function getIndex($string, $array) {
    $index = -1;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($array as $array_elem) {
        if(str_pos($array_elem, $string) !== false) {
            $index = $i;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $index;
}
```

Comment: Though this works, I dont think the TS means to get an index, but rather the amount of matching elements

Comment: Also, you now run an `$i++`, which can be incorrect. If you have keys from A to Z, key 7 will mean nothing :) I suggest the `($array as $key=>value)` method, and returning the `$key`.

Comment: Haha, Also: Please see my answer, the last example and then the `break;`

Comment: I ended up with a downvote, this answer doesn't provide the solution to the question, and if you fix all 'problems', it would be the same as Sharanya's answer (which also is incorrect)